# Error in loading jCarousel

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, jcarousel

I am currently migrating a website to WordPress from another framework. The site contains a dynamic horizontal carousel using jCarousel that shows the recent 5 posts. In the new website, I have included the script files, and have used the same script code as given in the old website. But, the dynamic jQuery part that is given by the script is not being generated. I am getting the error which says :

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'jcarousel'

The script that is used to call the jCarousel is as follows:

```
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function(){

featurecarousel(jQuery('#homepage-features-carousel .homepage-carousel-primary ul'));

featurecarousel_secondary(jQuery('#homepage-features-carousel .homepage-carousel- secondary ul'));
jQuery('.carousel-image, .carousel-caption-hidden, .jcarousel- control').removeClass('disappear');

jQuery('.homepage-carousel-loading').addClass('disappear');

if(jQuery.browser.safari) {
twoday.carousel1.next();
twoday.carousel2.next();
});
</script>
```

The Javascript function where the error is caught is as follows:

```
function featurecarousel(el) {

var c = el.jcarousel({

**Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'jcarousel'**
    animation: 600,
    auto: 5,
    buttonNextHTML: '<a href="#" title="Prev"><span>Next</span></a>',
    buttonPrevHTML: '<a href="#" title="Next"><span>Prev</span></a>',
    itemVisibleInCallback: {
        onBeforeAnimation: featurecarousel_itemVisibleInBefore,
        onAfterAnimation:  featurecarousel_itemVisibleInAfter
    },

    initCallback: carousel_primary_initCallback,
    scroll:1,
    wrap: 'both'
 });
 }
```

Please help me in debugging this issue. Am I missing anything simple and basic?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcom to StackOverflow. Please add some code, and you might want to add tag [tag:jquery] too.

Comment: Yes, provide your code if you want help.

Comment: Hi ..I have added the code.. Please look into it.

Comment: Hi.. Someone please help me out in this regard... I have been trying to figure this out for a long time.. Thank you.

Comment: Lotta help you guys were. The op clearly posted code over a year ago and everyone fled to the woodwork!